# Typescript 2: Custom Type definition in node_modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I publish a custom library called `my-library`. This library will be of the structure

```
node_modules/
    my-library/
        lib/
            index.js
            src/
              ...
        typings/
            index.d.ts
        package.json
```

Say now I export default something called `Application` from the index.js, so you use it by `import Application from 'my-library';`

Now, in my `index.d.ts` I want to declare its typing:

```
export = Application;
export as namespace Application;

declare namespace Application {
   function foo(arg1: string): object;
}
```

I know expect this to return an error but it does not:

```
import Application from 'my-library';

Application.foo(123)[0].blahblah;
```

Not only is the argument wrong, but so is the use of the return value. I don't know how I am supposed to add my type definitions so that the above works.

Comment: The [mqtt](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) module is a nice example that ships with types, they're using a folder called `types`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) to see where Typescript looks for definitions.

What you probably want is to add a `types` in your `package.json` to point to a custom definition file.

```
{
    "types": "typings/index.d.ts",
}
```